# Runtime error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method on "User.IsInRole()"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

It's an Asp.net Mvc 4 web application. It worked until I added `|| User.IsInRole("Admin")`. Why `User.IsInRole` cannot be in the lambda expression while `User.Identity.Name` works?

```
    private IQueryable<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _db.Items.Where(d => (d.CreatedBy == User.Identity.Name || User.IsInRole("Admin")));
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = Items.Include(d => d.Address);
        return View(items.ToList());
    }
```

The error was raised at `items.ToList()`.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsInRole(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the error because `User.IsInRole()` isn't something you can incorporate into a database query.

Try something like this:

```
 if(User.IsInRole("admin"))
    return _db.Items;
 else 
 {
    string name = User.Identity.Name;
    return _db.Items.Where(d => d.CreatedBy.Equals(name)));
 }
```

I'm not 100% sure without testing, but Linq to Entities may also object to incorporating `User.Identity.Name` in an expression.  By retrieving its value and passing it separately, it will be treated as a constant.

You can't combine tests for things in memory (like `User.Identity`) and tests on entity fields (which are really database columns) in the same expression. Linq to Entities will attempt to push all of the expression down to the database and will object if it can't.

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` works. It got the error after I added User.IsInRole("Admin").

Comment: That's good to know.  Perhaps the rule is, "You can't combine functions defined in .NET with tests on database columns".

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid method to linq. You should remember that all methods that are passed to link should be translated into a SQL expression. You can't call a function from .net or your assembly inside linq

Answer (score 2):

I would do your query separately for admin.

```
private IQueryable<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            var items = _db.Items;
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                 return items;
            }
            return items.Where(d => d.CreatedBy == User.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
```

Entity Framework is trying to convert it to a SQL expression which it cannot do for that.